# How to downgrade from PHP 5.4 to 5.3

Tags: server, apt, php, downgrade

Recently I upgraded PHP to 5.4, but it seems to be failing on me because APC isn't working with it, however this gave me no choice but to downgrade to 5.3, how can I do this?

I executed `apt-get remove php5` and `apt-get purge php5` then I removed the 5.4 repo from apt-get then executed `apt-get install php5`, it says it was installing 5.3, and I restarted `php-fastcgi` and `php5-fpm` but when I run `php -v` it says 5.4.

How can I downgrade from 5.4 to 5.3?

My server is running Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 11):

#### Downgrading PHP 5.4 to 5.3

In Ubuntu downgrading process is a really mess.
Here is the script which you could find it useful (**it removes PHP 5.4 and install PHP 5.3**):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge `dpkg -l | grep php | grep -w 5.4 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs`
sudo apt-get install php5=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-cli=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-common=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 libapache2-mod-php5=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4
sudo apt-get install php5=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-cli=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-common=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 libapache2-mod-php5=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4
sudo apt-get install php-pear=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-curl=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-gd=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-intl=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-mysql=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-pspell=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-recode=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-snmp=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-sqlite=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-tidy=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-xmlrpc=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-xsl=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4
```

Where the available versions you can check by command: `apt-cache showpkg php5`

After the installation, verify it by command: `php --version`

Please be careful and don't install any other packages without package version specified (like php5-xcache), otherwise apt-get will replace your PHP instance with 5.4 again!

To prevent this happening, you can hold these packages.

#### Holding packages using dpkg

To hold packages by dpkg, you can execute the following command:

```
echo "php5 hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

To hold all PHP packages, run the following command:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep ^php5 | sed s/install/hold/g | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

The following command will show you holding status of your php packages:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep ^php
```

#### Holding packages using aptitude

You can also hold packages using aptitude e.g.:

```
sudo aptitude hold php5
```

Unhold:

```
sudo aptitude unhold php5
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 13.x 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: How would go about undoing what's in your answer?

Comment: You mean go back to PHP 5.4 or recover config files? Config files should be kept as they're (no personal config should be removed). If you'd like to go back to PHP 5.4, then undo by to unhold the packages which you hold and reinstall php5 again e.g. `sudo apt-get install php5` with reinstall or removal/install.

Answer (score 4):

First execute `apt-cache showpkg php5`. There you will see version and other information about the package php5.

To install a specific version run `apt-get install <package name>=<version>`

In my Ubuntu 11.10 it would be `apt-get install php5=5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6`

Comment: What if ```apt-cache showpkg php5``` doesn't show anymore 5.3.x?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this guide will help you: [How to downgrade a package in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=321156)

So to download and install any package of any available version you have to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install Package=Version
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

I removed the repositories.

You have to remember that `php -v` runs the executable in the `php-cli` package so you have to remove that too.

So I did the following to get back to 5.3.10:

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-cli php5 php5-common
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-mysql php5-curl
```

Now this should show the desired version:

```
php -v
```

Comment: It installs the latest 5.6 for me.

Answer (score 1):

from the steps you described, you forgot to apt-get update after purging php5.4 and removing the php5.4 repo.

assuming you don't have the repo anymore in apt sources, if you run:

```
apt-get remove --purge php5 && apt-get update && apt-get install php5
```

you should be back on 5.3

Comment: In Ubuntu 13.x, by default php5 is pointing to 5.4.x