# How to uninstall both packaged and manually installed versions of PHP?

Tags: uninstall

I installed PHP by [following this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/566868/364614) on 14.04:

```
sudo -i
wget http://in1.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
tar -xvf php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
cd php-5.3.29
./configure
make
make install
```

I want to uninstall this now and also make sure there are no other versions installed (packaged or otherwise) and if there are, remove them too. How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, which version do you want to uninstall? The one you built yourself or one installed by package management?

Answer (score 13):

Packaged PHP installations can be removed fairly easily by removing the php5* packages. To be thorough, we'll target any packages that start `php`:

```
sudo apt-get remove '^php'
```

To uninstall something you installed from source, you would traditionally `cd` back into the directory you built it from and run `sudo make uninstall` ***but***  in this case it seems that [PHP doesn't ship a removal target for `make`](https://serverfault.com/questions/124385/uninstall-php5-installed-from-source).

That makes removing it incredibly hard. You can either manually find all the files it installed, or you [can (maybe) build a real package](http://www.linuxformat.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=9443) from the existing compiled version you have, install that over the existing files and then remove it.

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo -i
cd php-5.3.29
checkinstall
```

Accept all the defaults. By the end of it, it should have built and installed a `php` package (check the package name as `checkinstall` tells you) and then you can remove it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove php  # or whatever the actual package was called
```

If `checkinstall` doesn't work (it doesn't always), you're left hunting for files. Stalking through the Makefile and commands like `locate php` *might* help but with something as vast as PHP, it's going to be a long process. If you need a quick recovery, a reinstall (or backup restore, because you have those, right?) might be a better option.

---

As for verification, I'd just try running `php5` in a command line. `whereis php5` might be illuminating too. If they're returning results, you probably have more work to do.

Comment: you should make a note that this works, but it won't work unless you build the tarball as a package here - whereas the plain source tarball installed version can't be easily removed without that step, which seems to be swift's failing point in their answer below.

Comment: you can also use "whereis php" to locate php, it's a very handy command indeed.