# How do I downgrade php5.5.3 to 5.4?

Tags: php, downgrade

I am trying to downgrade php from 5.5.3 to 5.4.
I tried to find a 5.4 version using
`aptitude` versions `php5-common`

Package php5-common:

```
p A 5.5.3+dfsg-1ubuntu2                           saucy                     500
i A 5.5.3+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6                         saucy-security,saucy-upda 500
```

Package php5-common:i386:

```
p   5.5.3+dfsg-1ubuntu2                           saucy                     500
p   5.5.3+dfsg-1ubuntu2.6                         saucy-security,saucy-upda 500
```

How do downgrade to version 5.4?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of this question: [How to downgrade from PHP 5.4 to 5.3](http://askubuntu.com/a/220086/107450) only versions are different.