# Downgrading PHP from 5.5 to 5.3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, curl

now, I know that this question has been asked tons of times over the internet, but I followed lots of tutorials on the argument without being able to get to the answer.

This is my situation:

- Ubuntu server 14.04 newly updated on the customer's machine
- PHP version 5.5.9 that came pre-installed with the server
- cURL version 7.35 that I installed for the needs of my php script
- a PHP script that needs PHP 5.3.28 AND cURL 7.35 to run properly.

I've done that in Windows, it runs smoothly.

But now, in Ubuntu, I can't seem to find any solution.

I uninstalled PHP 5.5 and than tried to reinstall PHP 5.3, no errors in the procedure, but nothing is installed in the end (not even php-cli), in fact running

```
apt-get install php5
```

will do the trick and reinstall PHP 5.5!

I also tried to fall back to 12.04, but that way cURL rolled back at 7.22.

I've been struggling for hours, and I hope that someone can give me a hint on how to proceed.

TIA,
Riccardo

Comment: What have you tried here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/116254/how-to-downgrade-from-php-5-4-to-5-3?rq=1

Comment: First two of that. No notable effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can install an older version as follows :

```
apt-get install php5=5.3.28
```

Comment: your command does not work

Comment: E: Version '5.3.28' for 'php5' was not found

Answer (score 0):

Purge php5 and Compile from source like this?:

```
sudo apt-get purge php5
wget -O php5_3.tar.gz http://us1.php.net/get/php-5.3.28.tar.gz/from/this/mirror
tar -xzcf php5_3.tar.gz
cd php5_3
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I tried. It just doesn't install anything afterwards. I am doing it as root, so I skipped the "sudo"s

Comment: Not even an error?

Comment: No errors at all. It all goes fine, but if I try to execute a php script (via browser as well as command line) I get the obvious error like if there was no interpreter

Comment: Did it install? `dpkg -p php5`?

Comment: I see php 5.5 output using that command