# How to Install php 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.14 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt, php

I am experiencing problems with my PHP application with 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15.

I have identified what the problem is, but in the meanwhile I would like to downgrade to 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.14, because the application ran fine with this version.

I have tried to use this command in Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install php5=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.14
```

However it is not working.  It claims it can not find this version.  How can I install 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

Update your respositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Download and install from respositories:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-common php5-cli php5-dev php5-mysql phpmyadmin php5-pgsql phppgadmin php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-curl php-pear libapache2-mod-php5 php5-xdebug php5-codesniffer
```

ALTERNATIVE:

Download PHP5.3.10 from here:

```
5.3.10-1unbuntu3.15: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/i386/php5-gd/download

5.3.10-1unbuntu3.14: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/php5-gd/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.14
```

To Install:

```
ubuntu3.14 version: dpkg -i php5-gd_5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15_i386.deb
ubuntu3.15 version: dpkg -i php5-gd_5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15_i386.deb
```

If you get any errors configuring, depending on error you have to install dependencies:

```
http://zgadzaj.com/how-to-install-php-53-and-52-together-on-ubuntu-1204
```

Consider looking this article about PHP Downgrades:

[How to downgrade from PHP 5.4 to 5.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116254/how-to-downgrade-from-php-5-4-to-5-3?rq=1)

Good Luck!