# install php 5.3 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, server, apache2, php

I just installed `Ubuntu server 14.04`, I need to migrate my site from old server `Ubuntu 10.04` (which has php 5.3) to the new server,

but currently when i install php using

```
`apt-get install php`
```

i found the installed version is "`PHP 5.5`", how can i install **5.3**?

If it is n't possible, what is the previous possible version of Ubuntu i should downgrade to be compatible with "`PHP 5.3`"?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 different options:

1. try the solutions posted in [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116254/how-to-downgrade-from-php-5-4-to-5-3)
2. compile from source, although I wouldn't recommend this because you'll have to recompile after every security update

Btw, have you tried the site under PHP 5.5? Because if everything works well I can't think of any logical reason to downgrade.

Answer (score -2):

you can use this repository:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php5

Comment: This won't work - it's overridden by the software version in Ubuntu.